# Ordenar vários arrays object por valor

Tags: javascript, array, classificação

pessoas tenho a seguinte situação:

```
var input1 = {preco:valor1.toFixed(3), tipo:name1};
var input2 = {preco:valor2.toFixed(3), tipo:name2};
var input3 = {preco:valor3.toFixed(3), tipo:name3};
var input4 = {preco:valor4.toFixed(3), tipo:name4};
```

e eu gostaria de exibir os valores desses 4 arrays em ordem crescente do 'preco' do seguinte modo:

*Valor mais baixo: tipo: preco
Segundo valor mais baixo: tipo2: preco2
(...)*

como posso fazer para ordenar os 4 arrays de acordo com o valor de um dos objetos de cada um deles?

**EDIT**
para exemplificar melhor:

```
var valor1 = 50;
var name1  = "nome1";
var valor2 = 20;
var name2  = "nome2";
var valor3 = 60;
var name3  = "nome3";
var valor4 = 10;
var name4  = "nome4";

var input1 = {preco:valor1.toFixed(3), tipo:name1};
var input2 = {preco:valor2.toFixed(3), tipo:name2};
var input3 = {preco:valor3.toFixed(3), tipo:name3};
var input4 = {preco:valor4.toFixed(3), tipo:name4};
```

e depois de ordenar, nesse caso, deveria imprimir

**Menor Valor:** nome4 - 10

**Segundo Menor Valor:** nome2 - 20

**Terceiro Menor Valor:** nome1 - 50

**Quarto Menor Valor:** nome3 - 60

Comment: não estou vendo 4 arrays, estou vendo 4 objetos, o que você deseja é que a propriedade `preco` de `input1` receba o menor valor entre `valor1`, `valor2`, `valor3` e `valor4`?

Comment: não... existem 4 produtos... no input1 ele está armazenando o valor e o nome do produto1 assim como nos outros...
o que eu quero é que esses valores sejam ordenados mas que o valor1 continue no produto1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para ordenar pelo valor mantendo o relacionamento com o nome, você deve montar um array com as suas tuplas, então realize um sort...

mas como estamos ordenando por valor, não podemos realizar um `toFixed`, pois isto vai transformar o valor em uma string...

```js
var valor1 = 2002.46;
var valor2 = 1001.23;
var valor3 = 4004.92;
var valor4 = 3003.69;

var name1 = "name1";
var name2 = "name2";
var name3 = "name3";
var name4 = "name4";

var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", { minimumFractionDigits: 3 });
var inputs = [
    { preco: valor1, tipo: name1 },
    { preco: valor2, tipo: name2 },
    { preco: valor3, tipo: name3 },
    { preco: valor4, tipo: name4 }
];

inputs = inputs.sort(function (inputA, inputB) {
  return inputA.preco > inputB.preco;
});
inputs.forEach(function (input) {
  input.preco = intl.format(input.preco);
});

var input1 = inputs[0];
var input2 = inputs[1];
var input3 = inputs[2];
var input4 = inputs[3];

console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4);
```

a saida do codigo acima será:

```
input1: {preco: "1.001,230", tipo: "name2"} 
input2: {preco: "2.002,460", tipo: "name1"} 
input3: {preco: "3.003,690", tipo: "name4"} 
input4: {preco: "4.004,920", tipo: "name3"}
```

Comment: mas nesse caso serão ordenados os valores mas os nomes ficarão na mesma ordem... aí já não vai servir pois se a ordem dos valores muda a dos nomes também deve mudar

Comment: @Heathz, realizei a alteração.

Comment: exatamente isso... muito bom... valeu!